# Passing parameters to Odata Service in .NET

Tags: c#, service, parameters, odata

I have a Odata service which was added to Visual Studio via Service Reference.

I need to make following call to the service, but I am not sure how I can get this parameter passed.

URL Needed: https://host/odata/Project('abc')

How can I code the client call, so parameter will be passed as Project('abc') not as Project&=abc

I am trying to use generated Odata service context, not craft URLs manually via HTTP client, etc

Answer (score 0):

The notation that uses parentheses is used with key properties, if a property is not a key, then it is used in a "filter" clause. So just make sure that whatever property corresponds to a parameter value "abc" is defined as a key. And if it is not, then you can not use such syntax.